# Identify the manufacturer's logo on the connector used in IKEA OMLOPP LED lights

Tags: connector, identification

Can someone identify the logo on this 2-pin connector used in IKEA UTRUSTA/OMLOPP kitchen countertop lights?

The marking on the connector is 58A and some logo, which I can't decipher but it looks like NSSD or NESD or something like that.

The pitch seems to be 100 mil.

[image: Wire to board connector used by IKEA]

[image]

Hello,

I am also looking for this plug to replace plug from my very out of date ikea light. At the end i find this type of plug is called "mini-AMP", and it is very commonly used. So use keyword "LED mini amp 12v" or 24v, 30w, any param u need, you will find a lot options on amazon.

BR, Jingjing.

Comment: For me it looks like one of Molex ones, maybe Mini-Fit Jr.?

Comment: It's similar but different...

Comment: IKEA loves proprietary stuff. If they can make their products incompatible with anything that's not from IKEA, they typically will.

Comment: The part has a P/N and a logo. I don't think it is proprietary to IKEA.

Comment: You could cut this connector off and solder one of your choice which could handle current needed if you fail to find a replacement

Comment: That's not the point. I can do a lot of different things. But I want to know who makes this connector.

Comment: Isn’t it a molex 2520 connector?

Comment: I don't think that is the molex logo, I'll bet its a Swedish or European supplier, if so elfa would be the best distributor to search (with there convoluted search and part numbering system). Secondly you will not find a replacement for this cable off the shelf. Thats not how cables are made, only industry standard cables are widely available which this one is not, this one was built in-house by IKEA. That means the best you could do is find the connector and the wire and buy a crimping tool and put one together yourself (crimping tools range from 40EUR to 2000EUR depending on the connector)

Comment: It looks like you'd have to contact NINGBO SEN YI KAI ELECTRIC CO LTD in china and ask them if they'd have a extra NSSD looks like it means N-N-S-D => Nickel shell-Nickel body-Silvered pin-D=Plastic and is not the company name